# Как работает эта часть кода? map()

Tags: массивы, swift, функции, map

Совсем не понимаю как работает эта часть кода:

```
(number: Int) -> Int in let result = 3 * number
```

Как вообще понимать конструкцию `Int in let result = 3 * number`? Я нахожу очень нелогичным слово `in` после типа `Int`.

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

var new_numbers = numbers.map({ (number: Int) -> Int in
    let result = 3 * number
    return result
})

print(new_numbers)
// [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вам не понятно - называется "Замыканием" (англ. Closure). Если коротко, в скобках вы указываете параметр(в вашем случае number типа Int), потом идет "-> Int", что обозначает то, что Ваше замыкание вернет тип Int, после "in" идет сам алгоритм.

```
{ (parameters) -> return type in
    statements
}
```

Вот ссылка на документацию [Closures - The SWIFT programming language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html).

Используя функцию `map`, у Вас перебираются все элементы массива и с ними происходит следующее. Вы создаете константу `result` и присваиваете ей значение равное `3 * number`(number - это переменная в которой хранится n-ый элемент вашего массива), после чего Вы возвращаете это число в массив `return result`. Можно реализовать замыкание проще

```
var new_numbers = numbers.map({ (number: Int) -> Int in
    return 3 * number
})
```

Или же так

```
var new_numbers = numbers.map({ $0 * 3 })
```